# How can I make splash screen to full screen?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, splash-screen, navigationbar

I am trying to make splash screen to full screen. Let me explain with images:

[image]

As you can see there is a black bar at the top. There is also a white navigation bar at the bottom. The black bar at the top comes a few seconds after opening the application and causes the background image to decrease in size.

My splash_screen.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="fill">
        <bitmap
             android:tileMode="disabled"   
             android:gravity="fill"
             android:mipMap="true"
             android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

My styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light" />

</resources>
```

My SplashActivity.cs:

```
namespace OkuKazan
{
    [Activity(Label = "OkuKazan", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme ="@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Create your application here
        }

        protected override async void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            await SimulateStartUp();
        }

        async Task SimulateStartUp()
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }
    }
}
```

According to my research they are using something like NavigationPage but as I am a new xamarin user I don't get it. I would really appreciate if you can help.

EDIT 1:

I edited my styles.xml but it is still not working. The black bar at the top and the white bar didn't disappear :(

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>m>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light" />

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A theme looking something like:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>m>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
```

Then use the `AppTheme.Splash` on your Activity. This works on one of the Apps I work on. You can play around with the attributes. However, the `windowFullScreen` and `windowNoTitle` are probably the most important ones.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is still not working. I edited my styles.xml as you said.

Comment: For how long do you see your splash?

Comment: Almost 3-4 second. At the third second the black bar coming. The white bar always appear.

Comment: Hmm , interesting :D "await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)); " When I remove this line, the black bar still coming but disappears after about 0.5 seconds.